# Abstract Algebra Group Theory maximal subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $G$ be a group. Let  $\ g \in G, g \neq e $ where e is the identity element. How do you prove that there is a maximal subgroup of G, say H, with $g \notin H $ ?  Zorn's lemma maybe? Thanks.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}(p^{\infty})$ has no maximal subgroups. IS the group finite?

Comment: You can prove it using Zorn's lemma if the group is finitely generated.

Comment: Zorn's Lemma can show that there is a subgroup $H$ of $G$ that is maximal for the property that $g\notin H$, but such $H$ need not be a maximal subgroup of $G$. There need not be any maximal subgroup $M$ of $G$ satisfying $g\notin M$, or any maximal subgroup of $G$ at all.